# Why does BufferedWriter throw an exception on close if it's already closed?

Tags: java, stream

According to the JavaDoc for `Closeable.close`:

> If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.

However after calling `close` on an object of mine of type `BufferedWriter` (which implements `Closeable`) I am getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:118)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:264)
```

This seems to contradict the contract of `Closeable`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like the `writer` in this case is not already closed. Attempting to close it is what is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, based on the stacktrace, it looks like you are closing a `BufferedWriter` that:

1. is open,
2. still has buffered data, and
3. wraps an underlying stream that has been closed.

What happens is that calling `close()` on the `BufferedWriter` causes it to attempt to flush the remaining characters.  That cannot be done if the wrapped stream / writer has been closed.

If you wrap a `Writer` or `OutputStream` with a `BufferedWriter`, you should NOT directly call `close()` on the wrapped writer / stream.

Comment: Okay....so "the stream" of `Closeable` refers to the object itself, not any underlying stream

Answer (score 0):

From [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--)

> ```
> public void close()
>        throws IOException
> ```
>
> Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed,
>   further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be
>   thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

The [`Closeable` Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close--) specifically states that you should should mark the Closable as closed...

> As noted in AutoCloseable.close(), cases where the close may fail
>   require careful attention. **It is strongly advised to relinquish the
>   underlying resources and to internally mark the Closeable as closed,
>   prior to throwing the IOException.**

Comment: Not sure how this answers my question? The JavaDoc for `BufferedWriter` mirrors the documentation for `Closeable` in this sense.